# Visualization of all hcp voids

Tags: reference-request, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography

There are 12 tetrahedral voids and 6 octahedral voids in hcp unit cell but I can't find any image that can show all tetrahedral voids and all octahedral voids in hcp unit cell (the common picture in Google shows 2 octahedral voids and 3 tetrahedral voids). Could someone help me to draw or find visualization image of all voids in hcp?

Thank you.

Comment: A unit cell is not what you think it is.

Comment: On the left: http://ruby.chemie.uni-freiburg.de/Vorlesung/Gif_bilder/Strukturchemie/packungen_luecken_c.png (German: _Lücke_ = void)